# Unit test Angular 4 getting error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined`

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing

I'm getting error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined` on unit test, how to fix it?

part of my code:

**Spec**

```js
 it('makes expected calls', () => {
        const item1: item3 = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(item3);
        spyOn(comp, 'item5');
        spyOn(item1, 'item2');
        comp.item4();
        expect(comp.item5).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(item1.item2).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

if I remove this part of spec I get success.

am I using the subscribe() correct way?

Comment: Could you show the IJ in the constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try providing a mock `Observable` Jasmine spy `returnValue` for the spy created for method `isPeriodCycleOpen` to provide something for the component to be able `subscribe` to:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

it('makes expected calls', () => {
    const mockResponse = { cyclePeriodOpen: true, deadLineCycle: 'foobar' };

    const cycleServiceStub: CycleService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(CycleService);
    spyOn(comp, 'setChartData');
    spyOn(cycleServiceStub, 'isPeriodCycleOpen').and.returnValue(Observable.of(mockResponse));
    comp.getCycleStatus();
    expect(comp.setChartData).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(cycleServiceStub.isPeriodCycleOpen).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Hey man, thank you for help me, put one more `)` after mockResponse) ...

I got success =D

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the return value of the spyon method, try this:

```
it('makes expected calls', () => {
    const cycleServiceStub: CycleService = 
    fixture.debugElement.injector.get(CycleService);
    spyOn(comp, 'setChartData');
    spyOn(cycleServiceStub, 'isPeriodCycleOpen')
        .and.callFake(() => Observable.of('yourValue')});
    comp.getCycleStatus();
    expect(comp.setChartData).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(cycleServiceStub.isPeriodCycleOpen).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```